# Xcode 5 and iOS 7 Simulator/Device Crash with zombie error - Works on iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

ARC=Code that executes without exception under iOS 6, fails under iOS 7 (device & simulator) with:

```
*** -[UISwitch _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x14d50960
```

**Profile for zombies reveals:**

```
#   Event Type  ∆ RefCt RefCt   Timestamp   Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   Malloc  +1  1   00:13.542.198   Salon Clients   -[ApplicationSettingViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]
1   Retain  +1  2   00:13.542.696   UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]
2   Release -1  1   00:13.542.721   Salon Clients   -[ApplicationSettingViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]
3   Retain  +1  2   00:13.542.843   UIKit   -[UIView(Hierarchy) subviews]
4   Retain  +1  3   00:13.542.846   Salon Clients   -[ApplicationSettingViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]
5   Release -1  2   00:13.542.889   Salon Clients   -[ApplicationSettingViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]
6   Retain  +1  3   00:13.553.959   QuartzCore  -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
7   Release -1  2   00:13.553.959   QuartzCore  -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
8   Retain  +1  3   00:16.099.687   UIKit   -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
9   Autorelease         00:16.099.687   UIKit   -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
10  Release -1  2   00:16.101.161   UIKit   _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler
11  Retain  +1  3   00:16.102.913   UIKit   forwardTouchMethod
12  Release -1  2   00:16.102.935   UIKit   forwardTouchMethod
13  Retain  +1  3   00:16.212.121   Salon Clients   -[ApplicationSettingViewController toggleReceived:event:]
14  Retain  +1  4   00:16.213.223   Salon Clients   -[ApplicationSettingViewController toggleReceived:event:]
15  Release -1  3   00:16.220.297   UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _invalidateSubviewCache]
16  Release -1  2   00:16.220.326   UIKit   -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview]
17  Release -1  1   00:16.228.818   Salon Clients   -[ApplicationSettingViewController toggleReceived:event:]
18  Release -1  0   00:16.228.819   Salon Clients   -[ApplicationSettingViewController toggleReceived:event:]
19  Zombie      -1  00:16.229.176   UIKit   __31-[UISwitch _handleLongPressNL:]_block_invoke
```

There are, obviously, no manual retain/release cycles.  The very strange call at the end of this history includes _handleLongPressNL This is not a gesture recognizer that I've added anywhere in this class.

The code is adding a UISwitch to the accessoryView of a UITableViewCell and adding a target to call when the switch is changed.

The method called when the switch is changed, records the changed state into standard defaults.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Jim

Where the UISwitch is defined and added to the cell.accessoryView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSDictionary *prefItem = [prefSpecifierArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]+1];
    //NSLog( @"Preference Array: %@", prefItem );
    NSString *keyValueStr = [prefItem objectForKey:@"Key"];
    NSString * title = [prefItem objectForKey:@"Title"];
    //NSString * prefType = [prefItem objectForKey:@"Type"];
    //NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", keyValueStr, defaultValue, prefType );
    //        NSString * settingValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:keyValueStr];
    NSString * valueType = [prefItem objectForKey:@"Type"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    if (cell == nil){

        if( [valueType isEqualToString:@"PSToggleSwitchSpecifier"] ) {
            cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:18];
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];// autorelease];
            cell.contentView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

            CGRect toggleFrame;

            if ( iPad ) {
                if ( SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0") ) {
                    toggleFrame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 49, 27);//225+(768-370)
                } else {
                    toggleFrame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 79, 27);//225+(768-370)
                }
            } else {
                if ( SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0") ) {
                    toggleFrame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 49, 27);
                } else {
                    toggleFrame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 79, 27);//225+(768-370)
                }
            }

            UISwitch * toggle = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:toggleFrame];

            //toggleFrame = toggle.frame;
            toggle.tag = [indexPath row]+1;
            toggle.on = [prefItem objectForKey:@"DefaultValue"];
//            NSString * onString = [prefItem objectForKey:@"TrueValue"];
//            NSString * offString = [prefItem objectForKey:@"FalseValue"];
            //haven't figured out what to do with this information at this time, I don't know how to change the label text in such a way
            //that is durable across localization issues

            [toggle addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleReceived:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            toggle.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
            if ( SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0") ) {
                cell.accessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 0, 49, 27)];
            } else {
                cell.accessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 0, 79, 27)];
            }
            [cell.accessoryView addSubview:toggle];
            [cell.accessoryView bringSubviewToFront:toggle];
        }

    }//end of cell definition

    if( [valueType isEqualToString:@"PSToggleSwitchSpecifier"] ) {
        cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17];
        cell.textLabel.text = title;
        if ( [keyValueStr isEqualToString:@"fastRefresh"] && iPad ){
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Fast Background Refresh for Style Center Menu";
        }
//        NSLog( @"%@", title );
        NSArray * cellsViews = cell.accessoryView.subviews;
        for ( UIView * cellSubView in cellsViews ) {
            if ( cellSubView.tag > 0 ) {
                UISwitch * toggle = (UISwitch*)cellSubView;
//                CGRect cellFrame = cell.frame;
//                CGRect toggleFrame = toggle.frame;

                toggle.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
//                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:keyValueStr];
//                BOOL switchValue = [prefItem objectForKey:@"DefaultValue"];
//                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:switchValue forKey:keyValueStr];

                if ( ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:keyValueStr] ){
                    BOOL switchValue = [prefItem objectForKey:@"DefaultValue"];

                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:switchValue forKey:keyValueStr];
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                }
                if ( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:keyValueStr] ) {
                    toggle.on = YES;
                } else {
                    toggle.on = NO;
                }
                if ( [keyValueStr isEqualToString:@"display24Time"] ) {
                    if ( ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"display24Time"] ){
                        display24Hour = [prefItem objectForKey:@"DefaultValue"];
                    } else {
                        display24Hour = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"display24Time"];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code where you have added the switch control?

Comment: Also, what's the question? I don't see a question here, just a bunch of statements. I'm not sure what it is you want help with.

Comment: Could you upload a code example to see when happen the error?

Comment: seems that self is deallocated but the switch remains on screen

Comment: what is self? note that button don't retain their targets

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was registered for notifications of changes to defaults to capture changes made via the Settings App.

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(readDefaultsAndSetSwitches:) name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

The method readDefaultsAndSetSwitches: simply was reloading the tableView to reflect any changes embodied in the change notice.

When the changes to standardDefaults was initiated locally, (within the class receiving the notification), the exception was generated. Solved the problem with a global variable to detect this state and avoid reloading the tableView while the change was underway.

```
    -(void)toggleButtonPressed:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event {
    changeUnderWay = YES;
.....
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:modifiedString forKey:@"workdays"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    changeUnderWay = NO;
}

-(void)readDefaultsAndSetSwitches:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ( !changeUnderWay ) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```